# Find Regextype non recursive

Tags: regex, bash, shell, find

I'm trying to isolate some PHP infected files which includes 8 alphanurical chars from the /home directory and recursively.

I'm able to have them located once I'm on the directory with the command:

```
find ./ -regextype posix-egrep -regex ^./[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$
```

Or

```
find ./ -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$'
```

But as soon as I try from another directory:

```
 find /home -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^./[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$'
```

It comes without any results.
I have tried to add the flag -L (--follow) but it comes without any results and there are many. file system loop errors.

I have read many answers online which seems to be related on glob and find works.
I tried different solutions such as :

```
find . -type f -print | egrep '^./[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$'
```

Ideally the output should be the full path regardless of depth so I may quickly delete them all.

Comment: And with `'^.*/[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}\.php$'`?

Comment: That's working thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The main point is that `find` command regex needs to match the entire path with the file name. So, if there is are other folder/directory names before the file name, you need to consume them, too.

Besides, `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is better replaced with `[[:alnum:]]`:

```sh
find /home -regextype posix-egrep -regex '^.*/[[:alnum:]]{8}\.php$'
```

Actually, `^` is redundant here:

```sh
find /home -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[[:alnum:]]{8}\.php$'
```

will work, too.